# how to get some string between some symbol in php

Tags: php, string, preg-match, substr, implode

I have php string like this :

```
$text = '<p>Artikel 20 November 2015,</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="../../../fileman/Uploads/Karangan Bunga Launching MD/Concert of Ari Lasso/Other/press conference/pers release/P_20151123_141352 - Copy 1.jpg" alt="" removed="" block="" auto="" margin-left:="" margin-right:="" width="723" height="1000" /></p>
<p style="text-align: left;">Artikel 21 November 2015,</p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><img src="../../../fileman/Uploads/Karangan Bunga Launching MD/Concert of Ari Lasso/Other/press conference/pers release/P_20151123_141312.jpg" alt="" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" width="646" height="1000" /></p>';
```

I just want to take .jpg file from that string (ex: **P_20151123_141352 - Copy 1.jpg** & **P_20151123_141312.jpg**). I already try using preg_match_all but it did'nt work, maybe I just used wrong logic. Help me please :)

Comment: let's see what you tried

Comment: Show us your regex, maybe we can help you fix it